# Clickable calculator how do this in sequence?

Tags: php, sequence, calculator, clickable

My code:

```
<form method="get">
  <button name="one" value="1">1</button>
  <button name="two" value="2">2</button>
</form>


<?php 
$count=file_get_contents('count.txt');
$count++;
file_put_contents('count.txt',$count);



$one=$_GET['one'] ?? NULL;
$two=$_GET['two'] ?? NULL;



if($one && $count==1){ 

    file_put_contents('one1.txt',$one);
}

if($one && $count==2){ 
    file_put_contents('one2.txt',$one);
}

if($one && $count==3){ 
    file_put_contents('one3.txt',$one);
}

if($one && $count==4){ 
    file_put_contents('one4.txt',$one);
}
if($one && $count==5){ 
    file_put_contents('one5.txt',$one);
}

if($one && $count==6){ 
    file_put_contents('one6.txt',$one);
}
//----------------------------------------

if($two && $count==1){ 
    file_put_contents('two1.txt',$two);
}
if($two && $count==2){ 
    file_put_contents('two2.txt',$two);
}

if($two && $count==3){ 
    file_put_contents('two3.txt',$two);
}

if($two && $count==4){ 
    file_put_contents('two4.txt',$two);
}

if($two && $count==5){ 
    file_put_contents('two5.txt',$two);
}
if($two && $count==6){ 
    file_put_contents('two6.txt',$two);
}

echo file_get_contents('one1.txt');
echo file_get_contents('one2.txt');
echo file_get_contents('one3.txt');
echo file_get_contents('one4.txt');
echo file_get_contents('one5.txt');
echo file_get_contents('one6.txt');

echo file_get_contents('two1.txt');
echo file_get_contents('two2.txt');
echo file_get_contents('two3.txt');
echo file_get_contents('two4.txt');
echo file_get_contents('two5.txt');
echo file_get_contents('two6.txt');
?>






<form>
    <input type="submit" name="reset"/>
</form>

<?php 
if($_GET['reset'] ?? NULL){
    file_put_contents('one1.txt',false);
    file_put_contents('one2.txt',false);
    file_put_contents('one3.txt',false);
    file_put_contents('one4.txt',false);
    file_put_contents('one5.txt',false);
    file_put_contents('one6.txt',false);

    file_put_contents('two1.txt',false);
    file_put_contents('two2.txt',false);
    file_put_contents('two3.txt',false);
    file_put_contents('two4.txt',false);
    file_put_contents('two5.txt',false);
    file_put_contents('two6.txt',false);

    file_put_contents('count.txt',false);
}
?>
```

How to do it? 
Example:

- I click in `<button>1</button>`, write it 1
- I click in `<button>1</button>`, write it 1
- I click in `<button>2</button>`, write it 2
- I click in `<button>1</button>`, write it 1

etc....

Should be:

- 1121

**As I click it is write in the same order in which they clicked.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't a nonsense to build a *calculator* (or whatever that is)  in PHP?

Comment: This does seem like a pretty silly way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to make a kind of calculator which can add values and reset them, why not try the following:

1. Read the content of your file
2. Add the value of the clicked button tot the value of the file
3. Write the result to the file
4. repeat.

But surly there beter things to do then write a calculator in php?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
echo file_get_contents('one1.txt');
echo file_get_contents('one2.txt');
echo file_get_contents('one3.txt');
echo file_get_contents('one4.txt');
echo file_get_contents('one5.txt');
echo file_get_contents('one6.txt');

echo file_get_contents('two1.txt');
echo file_get_contents('two2.txt');
echo file_get_contents('two3.txt');
echo file_get_contents('two4.txt');
echo file_get_contents('two5.txt');
echo file_get_contents('two6.txt');
```

This:

```
for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++) { 
    echo file_get_contents("one$i.txt");
    echo file_get_contents("two$i.txt");
}
```